# Passing parameters from template1 to Template2 in Django

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

I'm developping a website with django, and i have a question about how my architecutre should be done, because i don't feel like i'm doing this the right way.

I have an API in my Views.py that returns a JSON. and i have two templates which i use to request my Views.py ( with AJAX ).

While both works fine, what i want to do is to pass from template1 to template2 while saving the parameters used in template1 to use it in template2

I have done a little drawing to explain a bit more what i'm doing [image]

What i'm doing now and what i think is not good is that i do a redirect from template1 to template2 with the query string i want to use in template2 without passing from the server. Do you think i should use the session to save the parameters ? what's the best way practice to do this ?

if that's not clear, what i want is to be able to share url of my template and then be able to initialize the composents of my template ( like Select and inputs) .

Comment: Yes, use the session. And note it isn't really helpful to think in terms of templates: all those do is display things. You should be thinking in terms of views.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share url between users it is rather not possible to use Sessions to keep those informations - users that are out of your session won't be able to get the information. In this case passing arguments by GET request (directly in url) is reasonable and not bad idea since data is visible to the end user finally - in inputs values.

If you need to keep it in one session (so not to be able to send the URL to your friend just to use it in your context) why not to just pass the arguments as context parameters when rendering the template?

```
    #views.py
    return render(request, 'template2.html', {'args' : args})

    #template2.html
    {% for arg in args %}
    ...
```

If it is not possible (when you are not rendering the template form view that have access to data) the Session usage seems to be only way. Then you can consider to use [Django messages frameswork](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/) rather than vanilla Sessions mechanism.